# Prove idempotent and invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A square matrix $A$ is idempotent if $A^2 = A.$

Prove that if $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix that is idempotent and invertible, then $A$ is the identity.

How do i prove this?

Comment: what have you tried? You have the equation $A^2=A$, you know that $A^{-1}$ exists, how can use that?

Comment: You could always multiply both sides of the equation by $A^{-1}$

Answer (score 5):

We have
$$I = A A^{-1} \overset{(*)}{=} A^2 A^{-1} = A (A A^{-1})=A I =A,$$
where we used in $(*)$ that we have $A=A^2$.

Comment: is this the final answer?
or do we have to use values of In to prove?

Comment: @shive Why not?

Comment: @  principal-ideal-domain  ohh is it?

Comment: @shive The question was to show $A=I$. I showed $I=A$ using multiple times the transitivity of the equality relation. The last step which I want you to do is using the symmetry of the equality relation to conclude $A=I$.